# Xamarin Forms Map - Polyline background thread?

Tags: multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm attempting to plot 90,000+ GPS LAT/LONGs on a Xamarin Forms Map.

Using basically the following to highlight my Polyline:

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/maps/map-overlay/polyline/

I want to ensure all the points are plotted/drawn in the background so it allows the UI to still be responsive. Currently its taking 5-10 seconds for UI to become responsive.

I've attempted code similar to the following but I don't believe it's correct.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    var plist = (from p in totalPoints
                 select new Position(p.Latitude, p.Longitude)).ToList();

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        map.RouteCoordinates = plist;
        map.MoveToRegion(GeoHelper.FromPositions(plist));
    });
});
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Which platforms does this happen on? Have you tried to profile your code to determine your performance bottlenecks?

Comment: Hi Jon, I'm seeing it on UWP

Comment: I'm thinking part of the problem is 90K lat/long points is perhaps too many for the Map to support? Not sure of a better way to draw out a driving route though.

Comment: @aherrick That is a LOT of polylines! Google's `Encoded Polylines` for each direction segment might contain 20/30 points (max) in order to "stay on" the road visually. How are you acquiring that many points for one route? If you are stuck with that many points from a 3rd-party system, I would do over-sampling on those GIS points to reduce the point qty to a much smaller smoothed sub-set for display

Comment: I see! Thanks that makes sense. I'm pulling every single point Google returns for each Leg/Step/Points. Are you saying I don't need to go the "Points" level?

Comment: note this is a long trip. Seattle => El Paso => Seattle

Comment: Here is the call I'm doing: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?sensor=false&origin=47.8248443603516,-122.238464355469&waypoints=|31.6787300109863,-106.195953369141&destination=47.8248443603516,-122.238464355469 Pulling ALL polylines which is around 90K points

Comment: I think showing all of them doesn't provide much additional value to the user. Consider taking a subset of your points, by either taking nth point (quite barbaric approach) or simplifying your polyline using something like Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm. Good luck!